# Turing Logarithmic Function

Tags: logarithm, turing-lang

I was wondering if Turing had a logarithmic function and what it was. If not, I was wondering how I could create my own logarithmic function without a table look up or brute force if it is possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there is no way to do it. Better off using brute force.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a solution: Turing has natural log function. You can use base conversions to get log of other bases

EDIT: bass conversion:

```
function getlog:
    6*log(6)=666
    logcycle(6)
end function

function logcycle:
    return getlog(logcycle(getlog(6))
end function
```

Comment: Can you include the base conversion formula because I am a dumb child?

Comment: @WIR3D Yes I included it